# Typing problem in photoshop cc 2014

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, arabic

I want to type Arabic text in Photoshop, but the text appears disjointed and the letters do not connect at all. For example محمد appears as م ح م د.

I'm using Photoshop CC 2014 on Windows 8.1 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before.

Simply the version you installed doesn't support arabic text or you install it without activating arabic text support during installation.

Just uninstall it and then run the installer and in **option** panel in the bottom left there is **language** choose **English يدعم العربية** .
If there is no option like that, then your installation package doesn't support Arabic language at all.

[image]